# ZendFramework 2 and Jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, zend-framework2

I've just started to learn ZendFramework 2. I wanted to create a Form in zend which was working fine. Now, i wanted to tune a little bit up with Jquery Datepicker but unfortunately i cannot make the date picker to popup.

I put the javascript directly in the layout:

```
echo $this->headScript()
        ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/html5.js', 'text/javascript', array(
        'conditional' => 'lt IE 9'
    ))
        ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js')
        ->prependFile('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js')
        ->prependFile('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js')
?>

here is a script opener tag 
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
here is a script closer tag
```

And here is my Form:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'date',
        'type' => 'text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Date:',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'datepicker'
        )
    ));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

i found this 2 error in the console:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Jquery   
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#datepicker").datepicker()')
```

Comment: Are there any javascript errors?

Comment: Only these 2 what u can see in the update section

Answer (score 0):

Think you should be using `appendFile` rather than `prependFile`

For example:

```
echo $this->headScript()
    ->appendFile($basePath . '/js/jquery/jquery.min.js')
    ->appendFile($basePath . '/js/jquery-ui.min.js');
```

If you take a look at the DOM you will probably find the JS files are being included in the reverse order that what you want.

Comment: Thank your for your quick response but unfortunately this isn't solve my issue :S

Comment: @user1291203 Have you checked the DOM? Are the files being called in the correct order? The JQuery UI path should be listed *after* the JQuery incude.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the hole script to the layout

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

```
    $(function() {
$( "#date" ).datepicker();
});
```